# Multiple image are not upload in the live server

Tags: media, nodes

I had the problem in uploading the multiple images.

Create a content type called "**Photo slideshow**" and add the field called **images**.

In the "**Photoimage field settings**" -> if I selected the "*Unlimited*" under "*Number of values*" field, I cant upload the single image.

If I change the "*unlimited*" to "*1*" then I can able to upload the image.

> Note: This is the migrated website (6 to 7).

Please give a alternate solution for upload the multiple images with image caption.

Regards
JVRK

Comment: Is there any possibilities settings to limit the upload images or files in drupal 7 core files?

Comment: Try to just select image and submit node without clicking upload button.